# Unable to emit to the specified client

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

`users[name].emit('private message',{msg: msg, name: socket.nickname});`

The line of code above is unable to emit to the specified client. users contain the data of all the sockets and name is the name of the client i want to send the message to. but it isn't working.

Comment: Could you expand your question with more of your code? What isn't working? Is it crashing or returning incorrect results?

Comment: more code sir, and what sort of error are you getting...

Answer (score 0):

you have to emit socket to a specific client like:

```
    io.sockets.socket(socketid).emit('private message',{});
```